# Two adjoining lines becomes clearer than two individual

Tags: qgis, polygon, style, outline

When having an outline style where the two edges interfere, they become much more dense in the color than when they are individual, see image below.

It is an outline of a polygon. The thing is that I'd like them to become just as dimm as the rest.

Do you have an idea how to style them?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have set a transparency/opacity on the outline. If so, add Another symbol level make it white and not transparent:

[image]

[image]